# AWS DynamoDB. Querying all hashes IN array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I know BatchGetItems allows for retrieval of multiple hash keys. To save on the read capacity, I like to know if Query provide same functionality via some "IN" keyword I can use? ie, all primary keys will be inserted into an array for Query to search "IN" in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Query` doesn't provide what you want. As per the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax):

> **KeyConditionExpression**: The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key value. The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests on a single sort key value. `Query` can use `KeyConditionExpression` to retrieve one item with a given partition key value and sort key value, or several items that have the same partition key value but different sort key values.

`BatchGetItem` is the only option that you have.